# Why does django community encourage the use of Postgres over Mysql?

Tags: django

Django community seems to encourage the use of Postgres, I understand that in a big project you probably don't want to use SQLite or such, but i don't know why they don't like Mysql that much.

just a quick example - Djangobook page 9:

> We’re quite fond of PostgreSQL ourselves, for reasons outside the scope of this book, so we mention it first. However, all those engines will work equally well with Django.

Postgres name is always associated with Django - just like Mysql is always associated with php

Comment: i don't want to start a debate, just wanna know if there's a reason for that

Comment: if i find a good reason, I'll start using Postgres

Comment: Even though I'm not familiar with Python, Django OR PostgreSQL, I can't find a single reason why you shouldn't use MySQL

Comment: You shouldn't use MySQL if you want millisecond or timezone support for datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer might be given to this quiestion is from those who writes the Framework...

But from what you can get from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/databases/) is:

> By default, Django starts a transaction when a database connection is first used and commits the result at the end of the request/response handling. The PostgreSQL backends normally operate the same as any other Django backend in this respect.

Django have a strong Transection control, and using a powerful `free` DBMS that have strong transection control is a plus...

Also,  previous versions of Mysql (before mysql 5.0), MySql have some integrity problems. Also MySql's **fast** storage engine `MyISAM` do not support foreign keys and transections. So using MyISAM have important minuses that its pluses...

And a wiki for [why Postgres is better than Mysql](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Why_PostgreSQL_Instead_of_MySQL_2009). Its quite old but it is good.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used PostgreSQL myself, so I can't really say much about the advantages it is supposed to have over MySQL.
But from what I've gathered, transaction handling is better supported by PostgreSQL out of the box. If you use MySQL, changes are that you will use MyISAM as storage engine, which doesn't support transactions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#transactions-in-mysql

Maybe the Django devs just got sick and tired of having to deal with bug reports where transactions didn't work, but the problem was due to MyISAM and not Django.

The South developers (the most used database schema migration framework for Django) apparently aren't to fond of MySQL either, which this message suggests that I've seen quite often with MySQL:

```
! Since you have a database that does not support running
! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had to
! leave it in an interim state between migrations.
[...]
! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
! easier-to-deal-with DBMS.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used Postgres whenever possible, partly because of maturity and because of the PostGIS extensions that add spatial data capabilities to the database. Even if I don't think I'm going to want spatial data in my application at the beginning its much easier to add it on if your DB supports it, rather than have to tear out MySQL at a late stage and replace it with PostGIS.

I think there is a spatial extension to MySQL now, so you might be able to do spatial operations in that now. But Postgres just does it and has been doing it for years.

Or I could spend $$$$$ for Oracle Spatial, I suppose...